# Make Facebook comment plugin in iframe scrollable

Tags: asp.net, facebook, iframe, plugins, facebook-social-plugins

So I used this code rather than the XFBHL/HTML5 code

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.phphref=http://9gag.com/gag/5852530&amp;num_posts=2&amp;action=comment&amp;scrolling=yes&amp;"
 scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;
 width:470px; height:400px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

As you can see I already set scrolling to yes but still the comments are limited to its dimension.Another problem is how can I limit the number of posts? the num_post isn't seem to work in this code.

Comment: When I use the tool the create the comment box code, choosing “iframe” gives me: _“This plugin does not have an iframe implementation. Please use the JavaScript SDK and the XFBML or HTML5 implementations.”_ Apart from that, and the obvious error in your code (missing ? to begin the query string) – you’re saying `scrolling="yes"` for the iframe, but at the same time format it with `overflow:hidden` …?

Comment: I changed that to scroll still its not working, anyway I used already the XFBML it already works in my problem

Comment: what is the solution to your question @MANGKANOR ??